# Strange behaviour of scrollbar

Tags: gvim, folding

When folding is toggled so that 800 line buffer is folded to 80 lines (with the window height being 50 lines), the scrollbar slider dosn't change its length and remains of the same size as when the buffer is unfolded. Is this behaviour correct? Shouldn't scrollbar slider size depend only on visible lines and change its size when the number of visible lines changes (e.g. after folding)?

Comment: Would either answer accomplish anything?  Have you considered reporting this to vim_dev instead?

Comment: Well, my question is whether this scrollbar behavior is normal and not configurable or it's just some plugin has changed some settings. If I remember correctly until recently the scrollbar worked correctly.

Comment: To find out whether the problem is related to a plugin, disable all plugins and see if the problem persists.  If it doesn't (and thus the problem is likely to be related to a plugin), disable plugins in turn to find out the culprit.  The report it to plugin's author.  Otherwise, try to reproduce the problem with a minimal config and report it to vim_dev.  It isn't that hard, you know.

Comment: You should probably report this as a bug, if you haven't already.

Comment: It was already [asked](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/MZtoTLwmeCo/aWe_9DaBBwAJ) and answered.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is intentional. [From the maillist](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=msg/vim_use/MZtoTLwmeCo/NANEk3mxBwAJ#!msg/vim_use/MZtoTLwmeCo/NANEk3mxBwAJ):

> This is because computing the size of the scrollbar thumb would require
>   going through the whole file and computing the folds.  That can be very
>   slow in a large file.